# Foreach statement array variable showing null

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, variables, null

- I have a script that has some functions defined, then some arrays created and variables populated (sorry if my verbage is not correct, very new to PS) with a foreach statement at the end.
- The overall script works (doesn't error out) and each function works individually and gives correct counts, etc.
- The issue is in the foreach statement, the $vpp variable, when looking at get-variable, shows all as {$null, $null, ...}, so consequently when I try to show the string from the get_VPP function with write-output $vpp it gives me nothing.
- Expectations would be a list of strings, such as managed, notmanaged, etc.

  - created functions (all are working individually)

```
Function get_vpp
Function get_all
Function get_byo
```

- open arrays

```
$devices = @() 
$byo     = @()
$vpp     = @()
```

- populate $devices variable with get_all and $byo variable with get_byo

```
    $devices = get_all
    $byo     = get_byo
```

- Filter out BYO devices from all devices
- then populate $getvpp array with get_VPP function
- and apply to $device variable

---

```
    foreach ($device in $devices) 
    {
      if ($byo -notcontains $device)

      {

       $vpp += get_VPP $device  
      }
    }
```

Comment: We will probably need to see a [MCVE] before we can help you sort this out. You have not shown enough code (IMO) for us to tell what is actually going on.

Comment: FYI, `$devices = @()` sets `$devices` to an empty array. So far so good. `$devices = get_all` sets `$devices` to whatever `get_all` returns, and that's not necessarily an array. The previous value of `$devices` and the fact that it was an array is lost.

Comment: Also, please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).